# jQuery infinite scroll on a table?

Tags: jquery

Does any one know of a good tutorial, or jQuery plugin i can use to add infinite scroll onto my table?

I basically want to add more rows to the table as a user scrolls down the page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just try this out:

HTML:

```
 <div id="postswrapper">
       <div class="item">content</div>
       ...
       <div id="loadmoreajaxloader" style="display:none;"><center><img src="ajax-loader.gif" /></center></div>
    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function()
{
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height())
    {
        $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').show();
        $.ajax({
        url: "loadmore.php",
        success: function(html)
        {
            if(html)
            {
                $("#postswrapper").append(html);
                $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').hide();
            }else
            {
                $('div#loadmoreajaxloader').html('<center>No more posts to show.</center>');
            }
        }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: should of mentioned i am using .NET lol :) thanks though

Comment: This work fine if 100% page zoom on chrome. But not working if not 100% page zoom.

Answer (score 4):

You can take a look at this if it suits your needs: http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y_infinite.html

Even if you're not familiar with datatables, it may intrigue you to use it, as for to implement this infinite scroll on a table you just have to add this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#example').dataTable( {  
    "bScrollInfinite": true,
    "bScrollCollapse": true,
    "sScrollY": "200px"
    } );
} );
```

to the populated table in the html (They have [4 ways](http://datatables.net/usage/#data_sources) to do that).

Anyay, IMO, worth checking out.

**edit:** As @SpoiledTechie.com says below in the comment - this info is outdate and you should look into the way they support that now: http://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10#bScrollInfinite

Comment: does look good, was not looking to add a scoll bar to the table, mainly use the one on the browser window kinda like FB uses i guess

Comment: in that case I think this may not actually be for you. I figured you wanted something like this because you've put "table" in your title.

Comment: does look good though, might be able to use it in the future. so thanks for directing me to it :)

Comment: this comment is outdated.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out following links:

http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/#.UBKSdHWi6so

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-an-infinite-scroll-web-gallery/

http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/how-to-create-infinite-scroll-pagination/

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

These are two of my favorite jquery plugins for infinite scroll.  Both have good examples of how to use them.

https://github.com/msjolund/jquery-esn-autobrowse

https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll/