# Infinite table in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table(#tabla-index) inside a div(#marco) and what I'm trying to do is to scroll the table infinitely. I mean when it reaches the last row, the first one is next, and 2nd, and 3rd, and so on.
Up to now, it scrolls the table until the end.
My js code is:

```
var $el = $("#marco");
function anim() {
    var sb = $el.prop("scrollHeight")-$el.innerHeight();
    $el.animate({scrollTop: sb}, 12000, "linear");
};
function stop(){
    $el.stop();
};

anim();
$el.hover(stop, anim);
```

Answer (score 0):

This partially depends on your database but here are some resources for you. 
[I don't take credit for the links below, a lot of them are answers to other questions] If these don't help could you please tell us what database your using?

Arranged by my perception of quality:

> [source 0](http://intercoolerjs.org/tutorials/infinite.html) Because programmers always start at 0! (sweet video)
>
> [source 1](http://www.satyam.com.ar/yui/2.8.0/infinite.html) (article)
>
> [source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11688279/jquery-infinite-scroll-on-a-table) (similar stack answers)
>
> [source 3](https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll/issues/157) (github)
>
> [source 4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HPVavdDzYoI) (youtube tutorial)

Happy Coding!

Cheers, SM

Comment: I'm working on a django project. Using sqlite database.